# Isolating pieces of code that segfault

Tags: python, ubuntu, fonts

I have a function call that sometimes produces a segfault. Right now I isolate this code by putting it in a separate Python file and doing `Popen('python snippet.py')` inside of my main script. Is there a more elegant way of doing this on a Unix system?

**Update 7/24**

I found the following to be convenient

```
if not os.fork():
  # do stuff that could segfault here
```

This has the advantage of not having to put all initialization code in a separate file. Apparently there's also `multiprocessing` module in Python 2.6 that supports inter-process communication

Comment: Generally speaking you don't fix segfaults by trying to "catch" them. A segfault screams, "fix me, something is horribly wrong".

Comment: By "isolate", do you mean "prevent it from taking down the main process" or something else?

Comment: aix: yes, I want to prevent it from crashing the main process

Answer (score -1):

Why not find it and fix it?

```
strace python yourapp.py yourargs and options >trace.out 2>&1
```

Then, after it segfaults try `tail -50 trace.out` and you will see how it leads up to the segfault. Typically it is a pointer that is garbled and points to memory addresses that are not part of the process. It is quite possible for a Python error to create such pointer errors if you are using something like ctypes to access shared libraries.

I

Comment: It's hard to guarantee that library doesn't segfault. If you run complex library on millions of files, eventually you hit edge-cases that were not debugged. I'm getting segfaults even in "mature and stable" libraries like xpdf

Comment: Of course there are no guarantees as to the cause, but that is a poor excuse for not trying to track it down a bit more. You may be able to find a way to avoid it if you can see where it happens.

Comment: I've posted segfault test cases so that people more capable than me could track them down: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=BANLkTiniy7BtySUF1NnCbg3gHzpCv-j5Cg%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=fontforge-devel